# SCLAlertView don't move when keyboard shows

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using SCLAlertView and add custom view with UITextView, my problem is when showing keyboard at first time the SCLAlertView not moving, see this picture

[image]

I write this code to move SCLAlertView when keyboard will show

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowFirstView:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideFirstView:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}



- (void)keyboardWillShowFirstView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGRect dialogRect = addAlert.view.frame;
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

    CGFloat top = (screenSize.height - keyboardHeight - dialogRect.size.height) / 2;
    NSLog(@"show........: %.0f", top);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = addAlert.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = top;
        addAlert.view.frame = frame;
    }];



}

- (void)keyboardWillHideFirstView:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    CGRect dialogRect = addAlert.view.frame;

    CGFloat top = (screenSize.height - dialogRect.size.height) / 2;
    NSLog(@"...hide.....: %.0f", top);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = addAlert.view.frame;
        frame.origin.y = top;
        addAlert.view.frame = frame;
    }];


}
```

Now when I hide & show keyboard manually in simulator "Command+K" it's moving right!!

[image]

Can someone help to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Try to hook the **centerY** constraint of the AlertView as **IBOutlet** and change it's **constant** as the keyboard is shown/Hidden

like this

```
 (void)keyboardWillShowFirstView:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
  CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
  CGRect dialogRect = addAlert.view.frame;
  CGFloat keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo]  objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

  CGFloat top =  -1 * (keyboardHeight / 2.0);

  self.alertViewCenterY.constant = top

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

  }];



}

- (void)keyboardWillHideFirstView:(NSNotification *)notification
 {

    self.alertViewCenterY.constant = 0

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{

     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

   }];

 }
```

**Note:** You may hook Top or bottom constraint If you want